# How to get network response even status code not 200

Tags: android, android-volley

I using API for login, if login success it return code 200 with respone. and if incorrect email or password will return code 401 with json object contain errors
the problem is that I want to get the network response even the request code not equal 200 like the image [image: postman response]

but volley throw exception `BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401`

here is my code

```
public interface OnResponse{
    void onResponse(JSONObject response) throws Exception;
    void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError);
}//OnResponse



public static void newRequest(Context context, String url, final Map<String, String>params, final OnResponse onResponse){
    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    //
    //onErrorResponse()
    //onResponse()
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, response -> {
        // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
            onResponse.onResponse(object);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "FLAG-1");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    }, error -> {
        Log.e(TAG, "FLAG-2");
        onResponse.onErrorResponse(error);
    }){
        @Override
        protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
            volleyError.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("zxc", volleyError.getMessage()+"");
            Log.e("zxc", volleyError.getLocalizedMessage()+"");
            return super.parseNetworkError(volleyError);
        }
    };
    //
    stringRequest.setParams(params);
    stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);
    queue.add(stringRequest);
    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
}//newRequest()`
```

Comment: stop using volley and use other http library

Comment: check your logs of zxc you might have get the response here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VolleyError` has the `networkResponse` attribute, it contains the response.

This is an example: `String response = new String(error.networkResponse.data);`

Answer (score 0):

Simply override `parseNetworkResponse` in newRequest() method like below

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Method.GET,
            <your url>,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //handle response
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //handle error
                }
            }) {

        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            int mStatusCode = response.statusCode;
            return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract response data from `VolleyError`.

```
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
   NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
   if (networkResponse != null && networkResponse.data != null) {
   String jsonError = new String(networkResponse.data);
   // Print Error!
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the network status code is other than 4xx or 5xx, Volley returns the response in the `onErrorResponse` as `VolleyError`. The response is received as a byte array so, you need to parse it to read the error and the message keys.

Below is a trimmed version of the required code.

```
final String failAuthError = new String(volleyError.networkResponse.data, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
ErrorResponse errorResponse = new Gson().fromJson(failAuthError, ErrorResponse.class);
Log.e(TAG, "Error Status: " + errorResponse.error);
Log.e(TAG, "Error Message: " + errorResponse.message);
```

and `ErrorResponse` is a custom class with `error` and `message` variables.

```
class ErrorResponse {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("error")
    String error;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("message")
    String message;
}
```